# whats wrong with my angular images code

Tags: angularjs, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have different images when user select option from the drop down box, display different images but i am getting same images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demo">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hourlies</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<style>

.container{
margin-top: 10%;
background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
}

.wi{
    width: 270px;
    height: 300px;
    border:3px solid black;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-3">
</div>
<!-- end of col-3 -->
<div class="col-lg-9">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select 
ng-model="selectedItem" 
ng-options="S.value as S.label for S in selectables" ng-change="fun()">
</select>

<br><br>
<img src='{{selectedItem}}' class="wi"/>
<img src='{{selectedItem}}' class="wi"/>
<img src='{{selectedItem}}' class="wi"/>
<img src='{{selectedItem}}' class="wi"/>
<img src='{{selectedItem}}' class="wi"/>
<img src='{{selectedItem}}' class="wi"/>
<img src='{{selectedItem}}' class="wi"/>
<img src='{{selectedItem}}' class="wi"/>
<img src='{{selectedItem}}' class="wi"/>
</div>
<!-- end of col-9 -->
</div>
<!-- enf of main container -->

<script>
var app=angular.module('demo',['ngRoute']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.selectables = [
{ 
label: ' vallay', 
value: 'http://www.quackit.com/pix/routeburn_track/routeburn_flats_t.jpg',
vlue:'http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/transtech/informationtechnology/preview/blue_screen.jpg',
value:'http://www.freeimageslive.com/galleries/transtech/informationtechnology/preview/chiclet_keyboard.jpg'
},
{ label: 'Tejas', 
value: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg'
}
];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post all your code (in a proper way)  or we won't be able to help you

Comment: What do you expect? You have 9 same images, of course it will render the same image.

Comment: Your label "Vallay" has 3 values however `SelectedItem` will parse only one and hence it is displaying only one. Also I'd suggest you to use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: You have to use `ng-src` not just `src` when using Angular.

Comment: Also, instead of `value, value, value` use value as an array and then `ng-repeat`, as PirateX said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added the function `$scope.fun` in your controller that you're calling from your dropdown; add it:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
...
$scope.fun = function (){
//Call API here, Pass selected model and in success method of api set $scope.selectedObj = response;
//response is may be something like this {name:"category1", imageSrc: ["photo1.jpg","photo2.jpg".....]}
};
```